# Supersmoother algorithm - tutorial?

Tags: python, smoothing

I came across a reference to a "Supersmoother" algorithm that was applied to prices in a timeseries.

Does anyone know of a tutorial in Python or whether Pandas has such a capability?

Comment: Are you referring to Ehler's supersmoother? If so, there is code for this on his website at http://www.mesasoftware.com/seminars.htm Although this is not Python code it would be very simple to rewrite.

Comment: Welcome to cross validated! Can you please give (quote or preferrably link) the reference you are speaking about?

Comment: I apologize for the vagueness - I was referring to Friedman's Supersmoother which has an implementation in R.

Comment: My current solution (workaround) is to just use the rmagic package to run the supsmu in R. I'm still working through the lower level details of that implemenation which is in Fortran so this is my current stopgap solution.

Comment: [Friedman Super Smoother in Fortran](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/supsmu.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a Python implementation of the algorithm here: https://github.com/jakevdp/supersmoother

You can install it with

```
pip install supersmoother
```

There are some [examples of its use](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jakevdp/supersmoother/blob/master/examples/Index.ipynb) in the github repo.